# find: missing argument to `-exec' with -exec scp {}

Tags: shell

I wrote a script which will login to Prod server and find a file and copy that to StandBy server.

My script is:

```
# ! /bin/ksh

ssh -l oracle -p 20022 IP_Address "find /opt/oracle/wcm/backup/export/ -name "*.DMP" -mtime -1 -exec scp {} oracle@IP_Address:/opt/oracle/wcm/impdumps"
```

After running the script I am getting:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I looked all the document saying put '{}' or \; at the end of line, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the `-exec` with an escaped command separator. From [the manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> ```
> -exec command ;
>           Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following
>           arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until
>           an  argument  consisting of ‘;’ is encountered.  The string ‘{}’
>           is replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere
>           it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
>           where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both  of  these
>           constructions might need to be escaped (with a ‘\’) or quoted to
>           protect them from expansion by the shell.
> ```

What you're doing should work; you suggested you'd tried to put '`\;` at the end of line', but it's not clear if you did it at the end of the whole combined command string:

```
ssh ... "find ..." \;
```

which wouldn't work and would still give the 'missing argument' error; or at the end of the `find` command, i.e. within the quoted command you're passing as an argument to `ssh`:

```
ssh ... "find ... \;"
```

You also have two potential layers of shell expansion. The `\;` will be expanded by your local shell, so the remote shell can see it as just `;`. You might need to escape it twice, I think, though it works for me either way.

You should also escape the quotes around your filename pattern.

```
ssh -l oracle -p 20022 IP_Address "find /opt/oracle/wcm/backup/export/ -name \"*.DMP\" -mtime -1 -exec scp {} oracle@IP_Address:/opt/oracle/wcm/impdumps \\;"
```

You might find it simpler to run this command directly on your prod server rather than remotely, but I have no idea why you're choosing to do that; or to run `rsync` locally on your prod server if you're doing this regularly. If you stick with `find` you should note the warning in the manual about the security problems, and consider using `-execdir`.